# Is a drain pipe passing under my footing a structural concern?

Tags: foundation

I'm connecting drain tile outside my house to a sump pump inside my house. To do this, I need to run a 4" diameter pipe under my house's footer. Will this cause any problems with the footer, or harm the integrity of the foundations?

Comment: Wouldn't this pipe provide an accelerated path for water **into** the house?   I don't know your situation but often, outdoor french drains accumulate water faster and in higher quantities than indoor ones, and need different solutions for getting rid of it.    Moving that water indoors, and relying on a pump that was designed for water that naturally finds its way indoors, seems risky even when the pump is working.  And if the pump fails you're providing an accelerated route for water into the basement.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a French (daylight) drain. It's simply a drain tile/sump loop.

Comment: @jay613, in regions with flat terrain there really is no option to daylight drain tile from 8 or 9 feet down. I've built many homes where there are both interior and exterior loops along the footing. They both drain into the sump via footing passthroughs. Battery-powered backup sump pumps are wise.

Comment: @isherwood this is new to me so hopefully this question makes sense, but if an indoor and outdoor loop are designed together along with pit and pump sizing for total expected water accumulation ... that's all good.   My concern here is OP's inside system was designed for water that percolates through concrete walls and floors, and he's opening a 4 inch conduit to what could be orders of magnitude greater flow.

Comment: Now I see what you're saying. Sump pumps don't have a substantial range in volume capacity. Just about any will handle typical flow from such a system. It mostly comes down to durability based on usage cycles.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be a problem. The footing is substantial enough to accommodate that small opening, and the wall above provides much bridging strength.

Consider that any such drain passes under (or through) the footing in most cases. Even if it's installed before the pour, it presents a weak area. This is common and acceptable.

Comment: If the OP is basically doing open cut under the footing, it would be worth backfilling the space under the footing around the pipe with non-shrink grout (obvs backfill and compact outside the footing).  If the OP is doing some kind of pipe-jacking, encasing probably isn't necessary.